# Show that the totality of the linear combinations creates a vector space over the field of real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Show that the totality of the linear combinations of $\sin(t)$, $\cos(t)$, $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ creates a vector space over the field of real numbers. Prove that the derivative operator (second derivative) is a linear operator in this space. Find the matrix of this operator, take $\sin(t)$, $\cos(t)$ as basis vectors.

Any ideas? I'm stuck.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  For the first part, all you have to do is to check the vector space axioms one at a time.

Comment: Can you write up some elements of the given set ('totality')?

Comment: Yes, it's e.g $2sin(t) + 3cos(t)$, $3sin(t) + 5cos(t)$. Sum of the two gives me $5sin(t) + 8cos(t)$ which is also in the set. I can also multiply the first element by -1 and it gives me $-2sin(t) - 3cos(t)$ which is also in the set. Is it what they ask about? The two axioms?

Comment: Those are the basic operations, yes.  The axioms are something else, however.  You must show there is a zero element, you must show there are additive inverses, and so on.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is a basic discussion of vector spaces, and it lists the relevant axioms.

Comment: Start by proving linear combinations of sine and cosine are a vector space by verifying all of the axioms. For the second part, for a transformation $\varphi$ to be linear you must $\varphi(\lambda v) = \lambda \varphi (v)$ and $\varphi(u + v) = \varphi (u) + \varphi (v)$ with $u$ and $v$ vectors and $\lambda$ a scalar. Check to make sure that the second derivative has this property.